# How to Print PDF using Android 4.4 Printing framework

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-print-framework

How to print already downloaded PDF using Android 4.4 printing framework?

I viewed the developer documentation. but no luck. Any example would be helpful

Answer (score 78, accepted):

After spend some hours on google i found the solution.

```
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
String jobName = this.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
printManager.print(jobName, pda, null);

PrintDocumentAdapter pda = new PrintDocumentAdapter(){

    @Override
    public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback){
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;

        try {

            input = new FileInputStream(file to print);
            output = new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor());

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                 output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES});

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ee){
            //Catch exception
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Catch exception
        } finally {
            try {
                input.close();
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras){

        if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
            callback.onLayoutCancelled();
            return;
        }


        PrintDocumentInfo pdi = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("Name of file").setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT).build();

        callback.onLayoutFinished(pdi, true);
    }
};
```

Comment: What kind of printers are supported ??

Comment: @abhishek http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/printers.html

Comment: very useful..just remove  **int pages = computePageCount(newAttributes);** from code.

Comment: @Dinesh Anandan, do you any idea about USB printer using android.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498746/print-text-on-printer-via-usb-communication-android

Comment: Thanks, perfect solution

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer, do you have any idea of how to print an image from an image url or a local device image?

Comment: @Dinesh Do you have any Idea how to print any office document like xls, doc, docx through this?

Comment: hi guys what is pda in printmanager.print(jobname,pda,null) please help me

Comment: @RavishSharma It's PrintDocumentAdapter use the code like 

printmanager.print(jobname, new PrintDocumentAdapter(){ } ,null)

Comment: This does not respect the orientation of PDFs, with the preview of landscape PDFs being rotated sideways.

Comment: This works fine for a .pdf file, but for a .txt file it doesn't show the layout and no way to print. Do you know how to modify to print a .txt file? Thanks!

Comment: Still, File saving as 0 bytes.

Comment: it will open android's dialog for choosing printers and other settings, is there anyway to prevent that, make it print directly without any popups?

Comment: Awesome man !!!!

Comment: Hi...in this code - `input = new FileInputStream(file to print);` - what I need to print in the place of file to print... Can anyone plz help me..