# Android Print Framework - Print Without Scaling/Fitting

Tags: android, pdf, printing

### Is there a way to force Android's print framework not to rescale a PDF when printing, as with Google Cloud Print's "No Fitting" option?

I'm writing an app which includes the ability to print out a PDF file. The user has the option of printing over Google Cloud Print's web interface, or (on 4.4+) via Android's native print service framework. For the latter, I'm using [the approach described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717189/how-to-print-pdf-using-android-4-4-printing-framework/20719729#20719729), which writes the raw PDF directly to a file descriptor provided by the print framework. Both print options are working fine.

However, when I use Cloud Print, I can specify a "No Fitting" option which causes the PDF to be printed as-is, with no enforced margins or scaling. I haven't been able to find a way to replicate this using Android's native framework - despite setting the layout to NO_MARGINS, the result is always a printout that has been scaled down compared to the Cloud Print copy. Here are the print attributes I've been using:

```
        PrintAttributes attribs = new PrintAttributes.Builder()
        .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4.asLandscape())
        .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
        .setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_MONOCHROME)
        .build();
```

Has anyone run up against this issue before? How did you resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you managed to resolve it?