# Printing in android only searching the printers

Tags: android, printing, android-wifi, network-printers

I have made an android app in that i have tried to print a sample text file,I want to use wifi connected printers,I tried this link[Wifi printing in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717189/how-to-print-pdf-using-android-4-4-printing-framework) But it only goes to searching wifi printer and do nothing,MY code is as below,Please help me and save my life

**code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public int pageHeight;
    public int pageWidth;
    public PdfDocument myPdfDocument;
    public int totalpages = 4;
    Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    }

    PrintDocumentAdapter pda = new PrintDocumentAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages,
                ParcelFileDescriptor destination,
                CancellationSignal cancellationSignal,
                WriteResultCallback callback) {
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;

            try {

                input = getAssets().open("sample.txt");
                output = new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor());

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;

                while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[] { PageRange.ALL_PAGES });

            } catch (FileNotFoundException ee) {
                // Catch exception
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Catch exception
            } finally {
                try {
                    input.close();
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes,
                PrintAttributes newAttributes,
                CancellationSignal cancellationSignal,
                LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras) {

            if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                callback.onLayoutCancelled();
                return;
            }

            //int pages = computePageCount(newAttributes);

            PrintDocumentInfo pdi = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder(
                    "Name of file").setContentType(
                    PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT).build();

            callback.onLayoutFinished(pdi, true);
        }
    };

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    public void printDocument(View view) {
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
        String jobName = this.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
        printManager.print(jobName, pda, null);
    }

}
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.wifiprint"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: are you fix your problem same problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should make button listener first for button event.

```
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            doCustomPrint();
        }
    });
```

And this print method for custom document print;

```
    private void doCustomPrint() {

    PrintDocumentAdapter pda = new PrintDocumentAdapter(){

        @Override
        public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback){
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;

            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

            try {
                // File for print.
                input = assetManager.open("abc.pdf");
                output = new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor());

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;

                while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                     output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES});

            } catch (FileNotFoundException ee){
                //Catch exception
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Catch exception
            } finally {
                try {
                    input.close();
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras){

            if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                callback.onLayoutCancelled();
                return;
            }

            PrintDocumentInfo pdi = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("print_doc.pdf").setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT).build();
            callback.onLayoutFinished(pdi, true);
        }
    };

    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
    String jobName = this.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
    printManager.print(jobName, pda, null);
}
```

And check this documents.

http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html

[How to Print PDF using Android 4.4 Printing framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717189/how-to-print-pdf-using-android-4-4-printing-framework/20719729#20719729)

Comment: wait..for my update on question,My dear friend i already declared it within my xml..like this     android:onClick="printDocument",SO it will be directly call tat function,is it?after clicking that button it opens a popup for pagelayouts and find printers,when i select all printers it goes to finding printers and nothing happens afterwards,,,!

Comment: have you read my question really?i already mentioned that link that you've send me...with no luck ..:(

Comment: Print function needs API Level 19. Please have a test minSdkVersion to 19 from 8, and don't forget add android-support-v4.jar lib to your libs.

Comment: can you please tell me what problems may be possible if no printer discovered?

Comment: ok dear,Please wait i am change as per suggested,and let you know,Thanks for help

Comment: Hello i have changed minsdkversion to 19 but still nothing is happening,it just searches the printers.

Comment: This is my sample project for printing directly from android device.
I have tested this with wi-fi printer and wi-fi direct printer.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12033943/test.zip

1) API Level 19 in manifest
2) 'android-support-v4.jar' library in your libs folder.
3) printer connection in local network.
4) check your phone setting > wifi > wifi network or wifi direct for printer connection.

Comment: Is there any solution because I am facing same issue