# Android Printing PDF document

Tags: android, pdf, printing, document, android-print-framework

I am trying to print pdf document that i just have created in my application.
I used

[How to Print PDF using Android 4.4 Printing framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717189/how-to-print-pdf-using-android-4-4-printing-framework)

above link

but there is error in :

```
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager)this.getSystemService(mContext.PRINT_SERVICE);
```

this line

says this error

[Please see this image for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYdgP.png)

And after this i tried to extend my activity with service then it says that , ondestroy clashes with service ondestroy.

so after that i created a service which extends PrintService there also same error occurs as in image.

Added service in manifest also and added the permission too. Please help i need to print the pdf file.

Comment: Asif Ansari: It is Context and not mContext. PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);