# Printing pdf through custom print issue

Tags: android

i convert the image into pdf form & i want to print this pdf file.I tried the google official printing custom Documents but in that docs it will create the pdf file then print it.How i can use my pdf file instead of generating programatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20719729/115145

Comment: @AlexiCoard Thanx for the help.But i am still not able to print the pdf.How i can pass my pdf file in that code.