# Send a pdf file to the defined printer

Tags: java, android

https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html#print-adapter

I found this but it is too complicated I think. I just want to send an existing pdf file to the printer. Is the above way is the only way? I couldn't find anything other that.

Comment: I must say this is best way.

Comment: But it is not clear how to implement PrintDocumentAdapter there. Any other tutorial?

Answer (score 3):

> I found this but it is too complicated I think

I agree. [Google doesn't care](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36995603).

> Is the above way is the only way?

AFAIK, yes, though see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20719729/115145 and [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.7/Printing/PrintManager/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/print/PdfDocumentAdapter.java) for basic implementations.

Comment: Shame! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your goals but, Your options are:

1. [Custom print adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html#print-adapter) - Like you saw. You can find easier implementation as CommonsWare wrote.
2. [Google Cloud Printer](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9633006) - An option just if your goal that each of user will print and set the printer itself.