# Printing PDF via Print Manager - Print Preview Doesn't Match Output

Tags: android, pdf, android-print-framework

I am using the example here to print PDFs via the Android Printing Framework:
[How to Print PDF using Android 4.4 Printing framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717189/how-to-print-pdf-using-android-4-4-printing-framework)

However, the print preview doesn't match the print output.  In truth, the output is correct but the preview isn't.  Is there any way to correct this?

EDIT: Google PDF Viewer apparently shows the preview correctly when attempting to print a PDF.  Is there some unknown way to get the preview to display correctly in the print preview?  There doesn't appear to be any solutions anywhere.

Comment: Which print service are you using. In reality the pdf that is handed to the print service is the same used to create the preview, but the print service could use a different pdf renderer to create the output where as the print framework uses PDFium: https://opensource.google.com/projects/pdfium, so you may need to file a bug against it

Comment: I'm using the Canon Print Service.

Comment: UPDATE - In Google PDF Viewer the preview shows correctly.

Comment: Post some pictures of how the pdf differs

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is  that data what you want to print , load throgh the webview and Print that data using PrintManager using webview adapter

we have Printmanager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintManager and print the data and this manager needs printadapter which will get from webview createPrintDocumentAdapter

```
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager)getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter;
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
    printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(jobName);
}else{
    printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();
}
PrintAttributes.Builder builder = new PrintAttributes.Builder();
builder.setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS);
builder.setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4);
File filePdf = new File(pathAndJobName);
printManager.print(filePdf.getName(), printAdapter, builder.build());
```

thanks,